# How to subtract DATE by day

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

in my Controller

```
$ldate = date('Y-m-d ');
$b =  DB::table('warehouse_products_sell')
               ->select([
                   'warehouse_products_sell.dueto_date'
                ])
               ->get();
```

my output

```
$b->dueto_date = 2017-10-26

$ldate = 2017-10-07
```

i want to check

```
if ($b->dueto_date  - $ldate < 5 ){
 alert('hi')
}
```

NOTE : 5 ( day )

not sure how to do .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:

```
$days = floor((strtotime($b->dueto_date)- strtotime($your_date))/ (60 * 60 * 24));
if ($days < 5 ){
  echo "less than 5 days remaining"; //it's php not jQuery
}else{
  echo "$days days remaining";
}
```

Sample example: https://eval.in/875753

Comment: @user8663822  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) library , so you may easily rely on it's cool API,

here is a quick example :

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$dt1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $b->dueto_date);
$dt2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $ldate);

$diff = $dt1->diffInDays($dt2);
if ($diff < 5) {
    echo "hi";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$DueDate = new DateTime($b->dueto_date); // Due Date
$ldate   = new DateTime('Y-m-d') // Your date

$interval =  $DueDate->diff($ldate);

if($interval->d < 5){
    echo '<script>alert("less than 5 days remaining")</script>';
}
```